# Installing MySQL Client on OpenWRT

Tags: installation, shared-libraries, openwrt

I'm looking for a way to install `libmysqlclient` on an OpenWRT (ver: Attitude Adjustment) wireless AP.

I've (finally) been able to successfully cross-compile a small C program for the AP, but when trying to install it I get an error indicating that the `libmysqlclient` dependency for my program cannot be satisfied.

Seems pretty obvious, right? Just install `libmysqlclient` and be done with it. If only I could figure out how to install the library...

Is it as simple as copying `libmysqlclient` (which I have on my main box) to the appropriate directory on the AP? OpenWRT uses `opkg` as a package manager but `opkg` has no idea what `libmysqlclient` is.

I'm afraid I'm a little out of my depth here and any guidance the community can provide would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot to add that in my research I've found that there are other packages that can be installed on OpenWRT, such as MySQL, that rely on the library in question, so there must be a way to install it. The Makefile for MySQL found [here](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages#libs) (under libs -> mysql) indicates quite clearly that it is dependent on `libmysqlclient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's just buried deep in the bowels of the internet. The following command will install `libmysqlclient` to your OpenWRT box:

`opkg install http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages/libmysqlclient_5.1.68-1_ar71xx.ipk`

However, this lib depends on a couple others, all of which can be found at [OpenWRT's opkg Repository](http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages/).